# how to change innerHTML of dynamically generated option form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem setting the innerHTML of an option form element.
The select field and option field are generated properly but the problem is that there is no value for the option that is generated.

```
<script src="jq.js"></script>


<script>
$(function(){
    var num = 0;
    $('#gen_select').click(function(){
        var sel_opt = document.createElement('select');
        sel_opt.setAttribute('id','status' + num);
        sel_opt.setAttribute('name', 'shi');



        document.getElementById('select_opt_div').appendChild(sel_opt);

        var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
        opt.setAttribute('value', 'mr');
        opt.setAttribute('id','boy');

        var opt2 = document.createElement('option');
        opt2.setAttribute('value', 'ms');
        opt2.setAttribute('id','girl');

        document.getElementById('status' + num).appendChild(opt1);
        document.getElementById('status' + num).appendChild(opt2);
        document.getElementById('boy').innerHTML = 'MR';
        document.getElementById('girl').innerHTML = 'MS';
        num++;
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="gen_select" value="generate select"/>
<div id="select_opt_div"></div>
```

I also tried something like this, but no luck:

```
opt2.innerHTML = 'MS';
opt.innerHTML = 'MR';
```

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @leyasu Sawada problem with your variable....opt is not defined...
make opt as opt1 it will work

Comment: and one more thing i suggest you is try to use jquery library efficiently so you can get less and beautiful  lines of code for eg: use ...$("#status"+num) instead of using document.getElementById("status"+num). Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery anyways, you could try this (does the same what you wrote):

```
var num = 0;
$('#gen_select').click(function(){
    var sel_opt=$('<select>').attr({
        'id' : 'status' + num,
        'name' : 'shi'
    }).appendTo('#select_opt_div');

    var opt1=$('<option>').attr({
        'value' : 'mr',
        'id' : 'boy'
    }).text('MR').appendTo(sel_opt);

    var opt2=$('<option>').attr({
        'value' : 'ms',
        'id' : 'girl'
    }).text('MS').appendTo(sel_opt);

    num++;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YVebc/)

jQuery is your best friend when it comes to DOM manipulation/traversal.

Comment: Thanks!I never thought I could also generate form fields using jquery.

Comment: You *can* do this, but it's incredibly round-about.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred and maximally-compatible way to fill in select options is via the `new Option` constructor, which accepts the text and optional value, and the select element's `options` array-like-thing (it's not really an array):

```
var options = document.getElementById('select_opt_div');
options[options.length] = new Option('MR', 'boy');   // Add option with text "MR" and value "boy"
options[options.length] = new Option('MS', 'girl');  // Add option with text "MS" and value "girl"
```

This is more reliable cross-browser than directly manipulating the DOM elements.

You can also truncate the array-like-thing by setting its `length` (as with an array), e.g. to clear all options out of it:

```
options.length = 0;
```

If you don't like the `options[options.length] = ...` syntax for adding options at the end, you can use `options.add(...);` instead. As far as I can tell it's just as cross-browser compatible. Note that that's `add`, not `push`; this is one of the ways in which it's not an actual array. :-)

---

**Update**:

I notice you're putting `id` values on your options. That's fairly unusual, but you can do it. After you create your option via `new Option`, just assign an `id` to its `id` property:

```
option = new Option("text of option", "value of option");
option.id = "unique_ID_of_option";
```

Answer (score 1):

The text inside an `<option>` may be accessed by the text-property

```
opt.text='MR';
```

Also note:
you set the attributes of an object named `opt` , but the object is opt1 (opt is undefined, so you run in an error and the script stops executing)

var **opt1** = document.createElement('option');
        **opt**.setAttribute('value', 'mr');
        **opt**.setAttribute('id','boy');

Answer (score 1):

try to append `option` to your `select` tag using jquery like this

```
$('#SelectID').append('<option value="Mr">Boy</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery you can set the value like this

```
opt2.val('ms');
```

or you can write pure javascript

```
opt2.value = 'ms';
opt2.text = 'MS';
```

In js value of the element is different from attribute.